# R aggregate column until one condition is met

Tags: r, filter, max, aggregate, plyr

so I´m having a dataframe of this form:

```
ID   Var1   Var2
1     1      1
1     2      2
1     3      3
1     4      2
1     5      2
2     1      4
2     2      8
2     3      10
2     4      10
2     5      7
```

and I would like to filter the Var1 values by group for their maximum, on the condition, that the maximum value of Var2 is not met. This will be part of a new dataframe only containing one row per ID, so the outcome should be something like this:

```
ID   Var1
1     2
2     2
```

so the function should filter the dataframe for the maximum, but only consider the values in the rows before Var2 reaches it´s maximum. The rows containing the maximum itself should not be included and so shouldn´t the rows after the maximum.
I tried building something with the `while` loop, but it didn´t work out. Also I´d be thankful if the solution doesn´t employ `data.table`

Thanks in advance

Comment: what if the maximum of var1 was in the first row while the maximum of var2 was in the third row? will you still pick the f2nd row or just the first row?

Comment: @Onyambu if Var2 has it´s maximum in row 3 (in regard to one group) that the first two rows of Var1 in that group are to be considered for the filtering. So the new dataframe/variable should in your case report the the value of Var1 in the first row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could do something like this:

```r
DF <- structure(list(
  ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), 
  Var1 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), 
  Var2 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 8L, 10L, 10L, 7L)), 
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))

library(dplyr)

DF %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
  slice(1:(which.max(Var2)-1)) %>% 
  slice_max(Var1) %>% 
  select(ID, Var1)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#> # Groups:   ID [2]
#>      ID  Var1
#>   <int> <int>
#> 1     1     2
#> 2     2     2
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Somehow R can´t find the function slice_max tho?

Comment: Maybe your `dplyr` version still needs `top_n` instead of `splice_max`. See https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/top_n.html

Comment: ... thus `top_n(n = 1, wt = Var1) %>%` instead of `slice_max(Var1) %>%`